# How to attach a blind to a wall when I need extra clearance?

Tags: mounting, brackets

I recently bought a Venetian blind, which comes with 3 mounting brackets. My plan is to screw these to the wooden window frame.

The issue is that the glass panel has been replaced by double glazing a few years back, and it protrudes 1 cm inwards.

The net effect is that **I need my brackets to have an extra 1cm clearing from the frame**. My plan was to buy 1cm thick softwood blocks and attach the brackets to the wall with the softwood in between to give me the extra clearance. Am I doing the right thing here? Is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end I used 2 small blocks of pinewood, the same dimensions as the brackets and 1 cm deep. I drilled 4 holes (one for each screw) on the wood using a 3.5 drill head, and I used no. 6 screws to affix it to the wall.

It all worked nicely, the mounting is solid, and you cannot really see the blocks of wood because they are hidden behind the blind itself. I'm just posting this because it might help somebody in the future.

Comment: Self-answers are accepted and encouraged! Thanks for coming back to let us know. Please click the check-mark next to your answer, too, so others in the future know that this has a workable solution.

Answer (score 2):

This may be barely more than a suggestion but I'll post it as an answer.

Rather than make little 1cm blocks, I'd use a strip of wood about 1cm x 2cm the same length as the blind's width.  You could buy a piece of molding or trim that's right, or rip a strip off a scrap of wood, or etc.

This way you can attach that strip to the frame at spots that aren't right behind the mounting brackets for the blind, and the screws won't interfere with one another.  Plus it will be quite a bit stronger and probably a better finished appearance.

Comment: "and probably..." leave us hanging just like the blinds! ;) This was the other alternative, and definitely better than 3 little blocks. 1 full-width strip of wood will look like it belongs there instead of looking like a bodge.

Answer (score 1):

Presuming the blinds weren't custom ordered or cut at the store, I'd suggest you return them and get a larger size so you can mount them *outside* the window casing.

I 100% prefer the "inside the frame" look, but if you don't have enough room to do that, mounding them outside will probably look better in the long run than bodging up a fix.

Comment: Unfortunately, they were custom made. The area is a bit complicated because it's a bay window, and I want each blind to fit the corresponding window accordingly. Thanks for the suggestion though

Comment: And that, @mkorman, is why it's important to provide _as much detail as possible_ in the question, so people don't waste time (even though there wasn't _much_ time in this answer) providing answers that are totally useless or already considered yet ruled out.